# Linux directory permission setting

Tags: php, linux, exec

I'm trying to rename a folder created by another user.

Lets say the folder name is **data** owned by `myuser` and group is `myuser`. These type of folders will be created using automated script run by the use `myuser`.

And now I need to rename those written folder via **PHP EXEC** functin which runs by `www-data` user.

I'm getting permission denied message but I've tried giving www-data ALL privileges in sudoers file and I'm trying find a another way to do this as giving ALL privilege for www-data is not safe.

Can I set default owner/ group or permission for every file/folder written to a folder automatically?   What is the best way to do this?

Comment: where is `data owned by myuser` created? in user home? or any other location?

Comment: change your automated script so that after its created the folders it does `chown www-data:www-data folderjustcreated/` or you could just have it do chmod -R 777 * in your created folder root directory though this is a massive security hole

Comment: @Dave `777` is like `somebody please destroy me`.

Comment: my advice, don't try to change files/folders inside user home. you may have to open up the user home and every user is going to be public read at-least. I don't think any user may like this.

Comment: as I said its a massive security hole

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add both `myuser` user and `www-data` user to the same unix group (i.e. `mygroup`)  and add group write permission to the created folders (the automated myuser script could do this)

Create group and add this as the user default group:

```
addgroup mygroup
usermod -g mygroup www-data
usermod -g mygroup myuser
```

Comment: Thanks, I cannot change automated script. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers! I finally found a solution myself without touching the automated script.

Reference:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory

and this:

http://www.library.yale.edu/wsg/docs/permissions/sgid.htm

Good luck, hope this helps someone.